# I want to retrieve sent mails from gmail account. I am able to retrive inbox mails but not the sent mails

Tags: gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I tried this code

```
Folder[] folderList = store.getDefaultFolder().list();
    for (int i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(folderList[i].getFullName());
    }
```

to find folders in my gmail folders. It just showed:

```
INBOX
[Gmail]
```

Answer (score 2):

"[Gmail]" is a folder that contains other folders, you need to continue down the folder hierarchy.  Or use list("*") to get everything at once, but note that that can be expensive.  I believe the folder you're looking for is "[Gmail]/Sent".